# how do I use the right insertion of AVL Tree

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree

This is the insert part of AVL Tree, I test the code and find out it stuck in the first line, which is if ( v == nullptr ), but I don't know why. If I give my project a data with 500 numbers in it, it will all show the a b c d e, and not the rest of the thing that should cout out. 
I put the whole insert part below. The storing data part is fine, when I cout out the stored data, the data showed completely perfect.

```
tree* insert( tree* v, int y )
{
    if ( v == nullptr ) 
    {
        cout << " a " << endl ;
        v = new tree() ;
        cout << " b " << endl ;
        v -> key = y ;
        cout<< " c " << endl ;
        v -> left = nullptr ;
        cout << " d " << endl ;
        v -> right = nullptr ;
        cout << " e " << endl ;
        return( v ) ; // return a int value
    } // if()

    cout << "   2    " << endl ;

    if (  y > ( v -> key ) ) 
    {
        v -> right = insert( v -> right, y ) ; 
    } // if()

    else if ( ( v -> key ) == y ) 
    {
        cout << " 3 " << endl ;
        return v ; // return v
    } // else if(), this condition is not allowed

    else
    {
        cout << " 4 " << endl ;
        v -> left = insert( v -> left, y ) ; 
    } // else

    cout << " 5 " << endl ;

    v -> height = 1 + max( height( v -> left ), height( v -> right ) ) ; // update the height

    int f = 0 ;

    f = thebalance( v ) ;

     if ( f > 1 ) // if the factor > 1
     {
         if ( ( v -> left -> key ) > y ) // if the data currently put in is smaller than the current node's left child
         {
             return r( v ) ; // do the rr spin
         } // if(), this is the ll spin

         else if ( y > ( v -> left -> key ) ) // if the data currently put in is bigger than the current node's left child

         {
             v -> left = l( v -> left ) ; // do a left spin first
             return r( v ) ; // then do a right spin
         } // else if(), this is the lr spin

     } // if()

     else if ( -1 > f ) // if -1 > the facor
     {
         if ( y > ( v -> right ->  key ) ) // if the data currently put in is bigger than the current node's right child
         {
             return l( v ); // do the ll spin
         } // if(), this is thr rr spin

         else if ( ( v -> right -> key ) > y ) // if the data currently put in is smaller than the current node's right child
         {
             v -> right = r( v -> right ) ; // do the right spin first
             return l( v ) ; // then do a left spin
         } // else if(), this is the rl spin

     } // else if()

     cout <<  "    end    "  << endl ;



     return v ;
} // end of insert
```

Comment: Seems to be a good time to learn what a debugger is

Comment: Please show us the call to `insert`. I bet you have `insert(v, y);` instead of `v = insert(v, y);`

Comment: Is this not the "storing data part"?

Comment: The way to make a program work with arbitrary data is to use small and systematic test cases that exercise all the code and test boundary conditions. Large amounts of test data makes debugging difficult, and if it's random almost impossible.